# Why data inside one column cannot be seen with select command in the terminal,but the data can be seen in server web view?

Tags: mysql, sql

Data inside column "ward_code" can not be seen with command while in web server view they can be seen.

[image: ward_code data not seen here]

[image: ward_code can be seen with web server view]

The above data were imported to the database with below command

```
   MariaDB [samaritan]> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:////kino.txt"
      -> INTO TABLE ward
      -> COLUMNS TERMINATED BY "\t";
   Query OK, 21 rows affected, 6 warnings (0.107 sec)
   Records: 21  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 6

   MariaDB [samaritan]>
```

I am just curious why in the terminal the data inside ward_code is not visible? Sorry for my English, Thanks In Advance.

After adding SHOW WARNINGS; immediately after LOAD DATA, I got the below

```
   MariaDB [samaritan]> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:///kino.txt"
        -> INTO TABLE ward
        -> COLUMNS TERMINATED BY "\t";
  Query OK, 21 rows affected, 6 warnings (0.083 sec)
  Records: 21  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 6

   MariaDB [samaritan]> show warnings;
   +---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
   | Level   | Code | Message                                         |
   +---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
   | Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'ward_name' at row 7  |
   | Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'ward_name' at row 17 |
   | Warning | 1261 | Row 21 doesn't contain data for all columns     |
   | Warning | 1261 | Row 21 doesn't contain data for all columns     |
   | Warning | 1261 | Row 21 doesn't contain data for all columns     |
   | Warning | 1261 | Row 21 doesn't contain data for all columns     |
   +---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
   6 rows in set (0.000 sec)

   MariaDB [samaritan]>
```

Comment: "Warnings: 6", so you could to `SHOW WARNINGS;` which might give a clue.

Comment: or you could do `SELECT HEX(ward_code) FROM ward;`

Comment: @Luuk SHOW WARNINGS; return Empty set (0.000 sec)

Comment: You must execute SHOW WARNINGS **immediately after** SELECT execution.

Comment: Show "C:////kino.txt" file content.

Comment: @Akina yes, thats what I am doing

Comment: Oops, sorry. Immediately after LOAD DATA.

Comment: @Akina "C:////kino.txt" this is just an edit of file location in my system. for security reasons I could not display the exactly location of the file here

Comment: I do not ask its pathname, I ask for its content (which is already shown on the screenshots).

Comment: You are not specifying the character encodings. Might be worth a try setting all parameters correctly to your needs rather than letting the system use it's defaults: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/foobar.csv" INTO TABLE abc CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';`

Comment: @supernova I tried your option but could not solve the problem

Comment: If you open the text file in an editor that can handle Hex characters (e.g. Notepad++) does it show non-printing characters in the WARD_CODE field?

Comment: @NickW . No . if I open the file with Notepad++ it shows the real values of WARD_CODE. the non-printing characters appears only when I open the file in terminal with command line

Comment: Sorry - that was what I was trying to get to: are there non-printing characters in the WARD_CODE field? As you've said there are, that is the reason why the field displays differently in different tools - as each tool is handling these non-printing characters in its own way; which may, or may not, result in the field being displayable in that tool

Comment: @NickW could this be a Bug?? Because the original value before imported were all non-printing characters.

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand. How can the original values all be non-printing characters? If that was the case, where did the printable characters (like BNJ, GB, etc.) come from?

Comment: sorry @NickW what I meant is that they were all printing characters. My bad

Comment: Still confused. So was your previous comment "non-printing characters appears only when I open the file in terminal with command line" true or not? Does your file contain non-printing characters or not?

Comment: @NickW true, The original file does not contain non-printing characters.